# Angular5 HTTPclient get issue with nested json

Tags: json, httpclient, angular5

HttpClient.get in Angular 5 is not returning data if data is in a nested json format. The code below works for non-nested json data.
Would you please let me know if I miss anything or what would be a way to get the data?

Code:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

export class ReportService {...
  searchByUser(userUrl: string): Observable<any> {
    console.log('userUrl', userUrl);

    return this.httpClient
                .get(userUrl, { responseType: 'json'  })                                
                .catch((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                  return Observable.throw(error.status)
                });
  }


}
```

---

```
import { ReportService } from '../report.service';

this.reportService.searchByUser(userUrl).subscribe(data => {
      console.log("Data :", data);
    });
```

---

Nested JSON Sample Data returned by the userUrl:

```
[
{
"userId": "JX",
"location": "CHANTILLY, XX",
"fullName": "SMITH, JX L",
"userType": "P",
"userStatusDesc": "Active",
"occupationInfo": {
"occupationTitle": "HR GENERALIST HQ"
},
"miscInfo": {
"rankingPoints": 15,
"searchTermCount": 1
}
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue was not with the HttpClient or nested JSON. I was able to have it working with the same JSON generated locally. And when I deployed the code it worked with the JSON generated under the same proxy.